# Why does git create iso-8859-1 encoded _BASE files for mergetool if the local and remote files are utf-8 encoded?

Tags: macos, git, encoding

When issuing `git mergetool` after `git pull origin master` `DiffMerge` which is set up as merge tool complains that the `_BASE` file can't be opened with UTF-8 encoding. `file -I [path to _BASE file]` shows that the encoding is indeed `iso-8859-1` whereas the `_LOCAL`, `_REMOTE` and `_BACKUP` as well as the local file itself are `utf-8` encoded. Furthermore the local file has no changes and is tracked.

Changing `core.precomposeunicode` to `true` or `false` with `git config` doesn't change anything.

I'm using `git` 3.6.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.